# Impersonate unknown error when reading a remote Access file

Tags: c#, remote-access, impersonation

I'm trying to impersonate a user in C# to connect to a Access file in a remote server. There's no reading or writting permisisons for all users, so I decided to impersonate a user with permissions to do the querys I need to do.

The problem is: when I do the impersonation all works OK (or it seems), but when I do the query and try to fill the DataTable, the execution is closed (I do the query in a try-catch block, but in doesn't capture the error).

One more thing is: when I execute this in my own computer it works, but when someone else tries in other computer with his own user (and tries to impersonate my user to have permission) is when the execution crashes.

Can anyone help?

The impersonation block is:

```
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Original user: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                System.Console.ReadLine();
                context.Enter();               
                Console.WriteLine("Impersonated user: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                System.Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Error when impersonating user. \n Error: " + e.Message);
                System.Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
```

The Enter function is got from the msdn:

```
        [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Assert, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public void Enter()
        {
            if (this.IsInContext) return;
            m_Token = new IntPtr(0);
            try
            {
                m_Token = IntPtr.Zero;
                bool logonSuccessfull = LogonUser(
                   m_Username,
                   m_Domain,
                   m_Password,
                   LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                   LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                   ref m_Token);
                if (logonSuccessfull == false)
                {
                    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new Win32Exception(error);
                }
                WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(m_Token);
                m_Context = identity.Impersonate();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // Catch exceptions here
                throw exception;
            }
        }
```

And the Access reading code:

```
            try
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Let's generate the adapter.");
                System.Console.ReadLine();
                PruebaIntegracionDataSetTableAdapters.ConsultaTableAdapter adapter = new PruebaIntegracionDataSetTableAdapters.ConsultaTableAdapter();
                System.Console.WriteLine("Adapter generated. Let's read the file.");
                System.Console.ReadLine();

                // this is the line that crashes and closes the execution
                adapter.Fill(dsIntegracion.Consulta);

                System.Console.WriteLine("File readed. Let's show the reaults.");
                System.Console.ReadLine();
                foreach (PruebaIntegracionDataSet.ConsultaRow fila in dsIntegracion.Consulta)
                {               
                    System.Console.WriteLine(fila.Apellidos);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Access connection problems. \n Error: " + e.Message);
                System.Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            System.Console.ReadLine();
```

I have tried to copy the file to a local folder, and the same thing when other user tries to copy it. If I don't do the impersonation, it shows the controlled error: no permissions. If I do the impersonation but the other user don't give my user permissions to write in his own folder, it shows too the controlled error: no permissions. Is when the impersonated user have all the permissions needed to copy from the remote folder and write in the local folder when it crashes.

Comment: what do you mean by `the execution is closed` ? What kind of error do you have ? Please try to run the program under VS debug and set [break when a handled or unhandled exception is thrown](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-can-i-pause-my-code-in-visual-studio-breakpoints-faq/) option

Comment: The execution doesn't stops in any readline (I have put in the code and in the catches to see what is happening).
That's the problem: When I debug in the VS it works perfectly. When I execute the binarys, it works too perfectly. The problem is when somebody else tries to execute de binarys in his computer. Anyway, I can give someone the code and he can try this. Thanks. I'll tell you something when I try this.

Comment: `when someone else tries in other computer with his own user (and tries to impersonate my user to have permission) is when the execution crashes.` but what is error message? Have you enabled the `allow impersonate` permission for `his own user` btw ? I suppose that another user must have a permission to impersonate and run code under your credentials. I have implemented similar setup when service impersonates end users using `LogonUser` call. However I've used the `NetworkCleartext` logonType parameter value.

Comment: sorry. I think I have not explained it well. It's when I execute this line: ```adapter.Fill(dsIntegracion.Consulta);``` when it crashes. The impersonation itself is done with no problem and the block where I made the ```context.Enter()``` works fine

Comment: The error is: ```The program '[18520] ConsoleApp1.exe' ended with code -3 (0xfffffffd).```